# Vim: autocomplete local variables/functions with clang_complete

Tags: c++, c, vim, autocomplete, clang-complete

I am new to vim and I am trying to set it up for use with C/C++. After reading about possible plugins for autocompletion I decided to try **clang_complete**.
I installed it and made sure it is working by using the included example file.

Completion after typing `::`, `->` or `.` works, but I just can't figure out how to get a autocompletion menu for local variables and functions defined in the same file or included via header.

Example:

```
void foobar();

void main()
{
    foobar();
}
```

When typing **foo** in `main()`, would expect clang_complete to be able to complete it to **foobar**.
Did I miss anything when reading the clang_complete documentation or is this really not possible?

Comment: It has been a while since I last tried it, but afaik it only completes automatically on certain points like `::` or `.` or `->` and for everything else you have to hit something (maybe tab when supertab is active, or ctrl-x p or so, the manual should tell)

Comment: You could use `<C-n>`.

Comment: For automatic completion, you can try the [AutoComplPop - Automatically opens popup menu](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) plugin; I don't know if it works with clang_complete, though.

Comment: You need to press `<c-x><c-u>` after typing in `foo` to activate user completion.

Comment: Sorry, this is not really related to your question, but you should check out the YouCompleteMe Plugin http://valloric.github.com/YouCompleteMe/ It's a bit hard to set up, but it's a lot faster than clang_complete.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions! `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` is almost what I was looking for, except that it is not really 'context-aware' (scope, privateness,...). The `<C-x><C-u>` shortcut by clang_complete actually provides this functionality, so I will use this most of the time. There is only one drawback with it: It can't complete the name of a variable whose datatype is defined in a header that is not found by clang. In this case I have to use `<C-p>` to be able to autocomplete the variable name.

Comment: @guini: I considered to use YouCompleteMe, but because of the complex set up procedure I decided against it. I use my vim installation on different machines, so installation should be as easy as possible and I like leightweight plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question "how to open the autocompletion menu" is to click < C-x > < C-u > (which means firstly press ctrl and x at the same time, then ctrl and u). Then you'll se a menu of user defined auto completions which is where clang_complete's completions are. If you're as lazy as me and you want the completions to popUp automatically, install an additional plugin like [AutoComplPop](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoComplPop). You can also switch to YouCompleteMe, which I don't like but may suit you needs better.